# How to make Alfresco ADF work with Community Edition 5.2?

Tags: content-management-system, alfresco, alfresco-share

I simply installed Alfresco 5.2 Community edition and installed Alfresco ADF 2 demo shell application:

https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-ng2-components/tree/master/demo-shell

But after running npm install and npm start, I get the below error when I login:

Request has been terminated Possible causes: the network is offline, Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin, the page is being unloaded, etc.

I follow various forum post to correct this CORS issue but none of them work. Even the instruction given in the readme of demo app related to CORS setting are incorrect as it refers to config/webpack.common.js which does even exist in the same demo app.

Is this because I am running Community Edition as it seems to suggest to run Enterprise edition? I want to build ADF on top of Community Edition.

I also tried against Alfresco 6.0 EA Community Edition  but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this [documentation](https://community.alfresco.com/docs/DOC-6615-12-installing-alfresco-ecm-as-adf-service-layer) or stop alfresco server,  download  [enablecors-1.0.jar](https://community.alfresco.com/external-link.jspa?url=https%3A%2F%2Fartifacts.alfresco.com%2Fnexus%2Fservice%2Flocal%2Frepositories%2Freleases%2Fcontent%2Forg%2Falfresco%2Fenablecors%2F1.0%2Fenablecors-1.0.jar) file and place it under `<alfresco-home>/modules/platform` folder and start alfresco.
[image]

Comment: I checked but there is no platform folder under <alfresco-home>/modules. There is only one folder called share under modules folder.

Comment: if not than create platform folder.

Comment: works now after creating platform folder and copy the jar there.